# CUDA and addressing bits in parallel

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu

I want to write a CUDA program that returns locations of a bigger array that hold a specific criteria.

The trivial way to do it is to write a kernel that returns an array of integers with 1 if the criteria was held, or 0 if it was not.

Another way might be to return only indexes that were found - but that would be problematic based on my knowledge of GPU synchronization (it's equivalent to implement a queue/linked list on GPU).

The problem with the first idea presented is that the array would be in the input size.

Another way I thought about is to create an array the size of log(n)/8+1 (n=number of items I check), and use 1 bit for each array location (holding a sort of compressed representation of the output).

The only thing I could not find is if CUDA supports bit addressing in parallel..

An example of how I am doing it now:

```
__global__ void test_kernel(char *gpu, char *gpuFind, int *gputSize, int *gputSearchSize, int *resultsGPU)
{
   int start_idx = threadIdx.x + (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x);

   if (start_idx > *gputTextSize - *gputSearchSize){return;}

   unsigned int wrong=0;
   for(int i=0; i<*gputSearchSize;i++){
     wrong = calculationOnGpu(gpuText, gpuFind, start_idx,i, gputSearchSize);
   }

   resultsGPU[start_idx] = !wrong;

}
```

What I want to do is instead of using int or char for the "resultsGpu" variable , to use something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CUDA GPU [can access items](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) on boundaries of 1,2,4,8, or 16 *bytes*.  It does not have the ability to independently access bits in a byte.

Bits in a byte would be modified by reading a larger size item, such as `char` or `int`, modifying the bit(s) in a register, then writing that item back to memory.  Thus it would be a read-modify-write operation.

In order to preserve adjacent bits in such a scenario with multiple threads, it would be necessary to atomically update the item (`char`, `int`, etc.)  There are no atomics that operate on `char` quantities, so the bits would need to be grouped into quantities of 32, and written e.g. as `int`.  Following that idiom, every thread would be doing an atomic operation.

32 also happens to be the warp size currently, so a warp-based intrinsic might be a more efficient way to go here, in particular the [warp vote](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions) `__ballot()` function.  Something like this:

```
__global__ void test_kernel(char *gpu, char *gpuFind, int *gputSize, int *gputSearchSize, int *resultsGPU)
{
   int start_idx = threadIdx.x + (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x);

   if (start_idx > *gputTextSize - *gputSearchSize){return;}

   unsigned int wrong=0;
     wrong = calculationOnGpu(gpuText, gpuFind, start_idx,0, gputSearchSize);
     wrong = __ballot(wrong);
   if ((threadIdx.x & 31) == 0)
     resultsGPU[start_idx/32] = wrong;

}
```

You haven't provided a complete code, so the above is just a sketch of how it might be done.  I'm not sure the loop in your original kernel was an efficient approach anyway, and the above assumes 1 thread per data item to be searched.  `__ballot()` should be safe even in the presence of inactive threads at one end or the other of the array being searched.